# using directory in IN(set) of for loop

Tags: batch-file

```
for /f "delims=" %%i in (set.txt) do echo %%i
```

This code is in demo.bat file.This works prefect as SET.TXT is in current folder.

but when I change the code to

```
for /f "delims=" %%i in (C:\users\demo\set.txt) do echo %%i
```

it does not work. but SET.TXT is also present in c:\users\demo\set.txt

what is the problem?

Comment: It does work -- supposing the file `C:\Users\demo\set.txt` really exists; what is the content of file `C:\Users\demo\set.txt`?

Comment: @aschipfl - may be the file path contains spaces?

Comment: @npocmaka, I assume the OP uses the file path mentioned in his question, so there should not be any spaces; if there are any, your answer provides the perfect solution...

Answer (score 0):

try with :

```
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%i in ("C:\users\demo\set.txt") do echo %%i
```